# How to bind data from dataset to listview?

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin.android, dataset

I have consumed a dataset from web service and I want to bind the data field into listview but I don't know how to do it as I just want to bind a few field from dataset but not all fields. The layout in list_adapter is the data I want to bind from dataset.

This is the Web Method for my dataset.

```
public System.Data.DataSet RequestTxnReceipt(string strIdentity, string strDateFrom, string strDateTo, string strLocIp, string strDomain) {
        object[] results = this.Invoke("RequestTxnReceipt", new object[] {
                    strIdentity,
                    strDateFrom,
                    strDateTo,
                    strLocIp,
                    strDomain});
        return ((System.Data.DataSet)(results[0]));
    }
```

Datalist.cs

```
DataSet ds = ws.RequestTxnReceipt(userName, "", "", "", "");
```

list_adapter.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/llContainer"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/transNo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="#20190506170757987"

    android:background="#ff2196c8"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff" />
<ImageView
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"/>
<TextView
    android:text="Date :"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:id="@+id/date"
     />
<TextView
    android:text="Recipient :"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:id="@+id/recipient"
     />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/currency"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"

    android:text="Currency :" />
<TextView
    android:text="Transaction :"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"

    android:id="@+id/transaction" />

<TextView
    android:text="Slip Verified :"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:id="@+id/slip" />

      <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnCamera"
        android:src="@drawable/camera48"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: no, i still getting error for the code

Comment: You can share a sample which contains the issue so that  I can test it on my side . Don't forget to remove the personal info .

Answer (score 0):

> in your adapter.cs

Add a property and method

```
public List<YourModel> dataSource;
```

```
public void AddData(List<YourModel> list)
{
  list.AddRange(list);
  NotifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Invoke the method and pass the dataset as params  to the Adapter.

In the method `GetView`

```
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    if (convertView == null)
     {
        convertView =LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.list_adapter, null);
     }

    YourModel model = dataSource[position] as YourModel;

     //for example , you want to set the text of textview
    TextView view = convertView.FindViewById<TextView >(Resource.Id.transNo);
    view.Text=model.xxx;             

    return convertView;

}
```

Or you can refer https://proandroiddev.com/android-data-binding-listadapter-9e72ce50e8c7

Comment: for the model i need to create a class for it? and the datasource is the dataset i have?

Comment: Yes . You can have a try .